# C++ beginner. user inputs single digit number, print the sum of 1 to that number

Tags: c++

wasn't quite sure how to title this question

example: cin >> 5, cout << 1+2+3+4+5

i'm in a c++ class in college and we are just starting out. I know i need to use a for or while loop but i have no idea what goes where in order for it to print what i'm looking for which is the sum of every number 1 to x (x being the user inputed number)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int x, i ;
    int sum = 0 ;
    cout << "Please enter a single digit integer: " ;
    cin >> x ;

    for(i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++)
        if(x <= 9)
            sum = x + i ;
    cout << sum << endl ;

}
```

i know this is probably way off, but i wanted to give you guys what i have so far. please help!

Comment: you want total sum right? for example cin>> 6 then you want your sum is 21 right?

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just `cout << x*(x+1)/2 << endl;`

Comment: I would change "-" to "to" in your title and discussion. Most people will interpret "-" as "minus" and be confused.

Comment: @mfripp done. thanks for the advice.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the instructions for the program was to use a loop. Therefore i have no choice. however i'll keep your advice in mind for future projects.

Comment: @Mojo `do { cout << x*(x+1)/2 << endl; } while (0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. remove the `if`. It does not affect your code. (Just ruins it if `x > 9`)
2. `sum = sum + i;` otherwise, you just overwrite its value. More elegant would be `sum += i;`

That should look like that:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a single digit integer: " ;
    cin >> x ;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++)
        sum += i;
    cout << sum << endl ;
}
```

As others noted, you can use the mathematical solution that states

[image: sum(i) from i=1 to n = n * (n+1) / 2]

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a single digit integer: " ;
    cin >> x ;
    cout << x * (x + 1) / 2 << endl ;
}
```

Comment: that did the trick. thank you so much! can't believe i missed something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to denote loop body. Accumulate

```
sum += i;  // sum = sum + i
```

instead of overwriting `sum = x + i`.

```
for(i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++) {
    sum = sum + i; // or sum += i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0, i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a single digit integer: " ;
    cin >> x ;

    for(i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++)
            sum += i ;
    cout << sum << endl ;

}
```